# IIS Re-Write Rule - Hide Directory (Rule Not Working Correctly)

Tags: iis, redirect, url-rewriting, hide

I have constructed a re-write rule with help from this website.
But I am still having a small problem.

My objective is to remove a certain directory from a URL.

For example:

```
www.mywebsite.com/uk/editions/
```

should be re-written to

```
www.mywebsite.com/editions/
```

*( removing the directory UK )*

The above scenario is now working for all URLS, except one.

The UK homepage is physically located here. (`index.html`)

```
www.mywebsite.com/uk/
```

And the correct re-write rule should display the URL as

```
www.mywebsite.com
```

instead it is showing the www root `index.html` instead of the `uk/index.html` page.

BUT if I specify the index page within the URL like so

```
www.mywebsite.com/uk/index.html
```

it correctly rewrites the URL to

```
www.mywebsite.com
```

and shows the UK index page and not the www root index page.

The rules I am using is as follows:

```
<rule name="Hide UK Directory in URL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^uk$|^uk/(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mywebsite\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>

<rule name="Rewrite the URL after UK is hidden" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(?!uk)(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.mywebsite\.com$" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="uk/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problems comes from the second rule your have (`Rewrite the URL after UK is hidden`).

In your conditions, you have:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
```

Those 2 lines mean, if a requested URL matches physical path to a file or directory, it won't execute the rewrite.

When you request `www.mywebsite.com`, it matches a physical path to a directory, so the rule isn't executed.

Comment: Great thank you, I will modify my rule and let you know how I get on.